# A familiar sequence?

Tags: knowledge

1. D 11876
2. h 18422
3. R 5373
4. G 19114
5. S ?

What number is represented by the question mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are..

> ..the top ranked users of the Puzzling Stack Exchange and their user id's.

> Deusovi user:11876

> hexomino user:18422

> Rand al'Thor user:5373

> Gareth McCaughan user:19114

And the fifth..

> Stiv user:60644

Comment: Yep you got it! This puzzle may become invalid in the future though...

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Is that a challenge?! ;-)

Comment: Hehe it sure is :) Judging by the rate you are climbing up, I don't think you will have any problems in becoming our #1

Comment: @Stiv I was secretly hoping that you would get to answer this puzzle. I think you were close to doing that.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Ha! I think you underestimate the stamina of those already at the top :) Got to be honest, I was barking up the wrong tree with this one, since all of the numbers appeared to be valid dates: 11/8/76, 18/4/22, 5/3/73 and 19/1/14.